# Equivalent strip_tags of PHP in javascript with allowed tags

Tags: javascript, strip-tags

I used this code to strip all tags but I wan't to save some tags like  and so on... How can I do?
I can't understand how can I filter tags

```
/***************************************************
    STRIP HTML TAGS
    ****************************************************/
    function strip_tags(html){

        //PROCESS STRING
        if(arguments.length < 3) {
            html=html.replace(/<\/?(?!\!)[^>]*>/gi, '');
        } else {
            var allowed = arguments[1];
            var specified = eval("["+arguments[2]+"]");
            if(allowed){
                var regex='</?(?!(' + specified.join('|') + '))\b[^>]*>';
                html=html.replace(new RegExp(regex, 'gi'), '');
            } else{
                var regex='</?(' + specified.join('|') + ')\b[^>]*>';
                html=html.replace(new RegExp(regex, 'gi'), '');
            }
        }

        //CHANGE NAME TO CLEAN JUST BECAUSE 
        var clean_string = html;

        //RETURN THE CLEAN STRING
        return clean_string;
```

**EDIT******
This is my HTML code

```
<body class="portrait" onLoad="prepareImages()">
    <div id="title_wrapper"><h2 id="title"><a href="[[[LINK]]]">[[[TITLE]]]</a></h2></div>
    <h2 id="subtitle">[[[DATE]]]</h2>
     <div id="content">
        [[[FULL CONTENT]]] etc....
    </div>
```

I used your function in this way (what I must replace is the: [[[FULL CONTENT]]] etc....)

```
(strip_tags(contentElem,"<img>");
```

without results. How can I rewrite the [[[FULL CONTENT]]] etc.... with the [[[FULL CONTENT]]] etc.... without html tags except ?

Comment: FYI, don't use regex because [bad things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/266535) will happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eval? Ugh, that is really ugly code. It matches all tags by using a regular expression pattern.

- If the function call has less than 3 parameters, it just strips all tags.
- If the function call has at least 3 parameters:

  - The third parameter is a string like `"a", "b", "strong"`. The quotes are required, thanks to the ugly <strike>`evil`</strike> `eval` construct.
  - if the second parameter is a truth-value (`true` for example), the third parameter is the list of tags that are allowed
  - if the second parameter is a false-value (`false` for example), the third parameter is the list of tags that are denied

If you need a proper `strip_tags` function, have a look at http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535

Comment: @UsiUsi I assumed that you were familiar with PHP and its [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip-tags) function. What do you exactly want to achieve? Replace a part of a text *or* replacing the contents of the page?

Comment: replacing the contents of the page!

Comment: I don't see the link between `strip_tags` and your actual goal, but replacing the contents of an element with ID `content` can be done with `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<b>content</b> <i>here</i>";`

Comment: This is more a comment on the OP than an actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the strip_tags() with allowable tags (from phpjs.org ).

```
// allow can be a string like '<b><i>'
function strip_tags(str, allow) {
  // making sure the allow arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  allow = (((allow || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join('');

  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi;
  var commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return str.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
    return allow.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
  });
}
```

Comment: i can tseem to get this to recognize line breaks `\n`

Comment: I see this function banded all over SO. Could at least get rid of the commentsAndPhpTags part.

Comment: Would be really useful if the strip_tags could remove attributes also like id, class…

Answer (score -1):

This operation is far simpler if you use the DOM. I don't know why people are trying to use regular expressions for this.

```
/**
 * Removes all tags with the provided tagName.
 * @param {Element} el The root element.
 * @param {string} tagName The tagName to match.
 * @example
 *   >> document.body.innerHTML;
 *   "<p><img src="foo.jpg">Some <strong>text</strong></p>"
 *   >> stripTags(document.body, 'img');
 *   undefined
 *   >> document.body.innerHTML;
 *   "<p>Some <strong>text</strong></p>"
 *   >> stripTags(document.body, 'strong');
 *   undefined
 *   >> document.body.innerHTML;
 *   "<p>Some text</p>"
 */
function stripTags(el, tagName) {
  var els = el.getElementsByTagName(tagName.toUpperCase());
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    while (els[i].firstChild)
      els[i].parentNode.insertBefore(els[i].removeChild(els[i].firstChild), els[i]);
    els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i--]);
  }
}
```

That will remove all tags (not their contents), which I think is how `strip_tags` behaves.

Comment: This may work in the OP's case, but often we want to strip tags from an HTML string which is not part of the DOM.  The title of the post suggests that too - i.e. an equivalent of PHP's `strip_tags`, which works on an HTML string, not the DOM.